# Multiplicative ARIMA model

Tags: r

Given this ARIMA model:

```
(1-0.8B)*(1-0.2B^6)*(1-B)Y_t = epsilon_t
```

Where the multiplicative model is (1,1,0*(1,1,0)_6 (seasonal component=6).
Is there any tool to predict new values from this model (such as the 10th or 11th values) given some initial set of values such as :

```
y <- c(1,4,5,2,0,8,9,4,-3,-3)
```

I tried

```
arima(y,order=c(1,1,0),seasonal=list(order=c(1,1,0),period=6))

 error: initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
```

Comment: You get an errer because you don't have enough values in your vector y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can predict ahead with the `predict()` function:

```
> y=c(1,4,5,2,0,8,9,4,-3,-3)
> mymodel = arima(c(1,4,5,2,0,8,9,4,-3,-3) ,order=c(1,1,0),seasonal=list(order=c(1,1,0), period=2))
> mymodel

Call:
arima(x = c(1, 4, 5, 2, 0, 8, 9, 4, -3, -3), order = c(1, 1, 0), seasonal = list(order = c(1, 
    1, 0), period = 2))

Coefficients:
         ar1     sar1
      0.7368  -0.9169
s.e.  0.3696   0.1089

sigma^2 estimated as 11.25:  log likelihood = -20.23,  aic = 46.46


> predict(mymodel, n.ahead = 5)
$pred
Time Series:
Start = 11 
End = 15 
Frequency = 1 
[1]  -7.763438 -16.104376 -25.686464 -28.419524 -35.086436

$se
Time Series:
Start = 11 
End = 15 
Frequency = 1 
[1]  3.354151  6.722215 10.392430 14.061929 19.640317
```

I reduced the period so that your model has a sufficiently long data vector.

Comment: Is this a multiplicative model?

Comment: The thing is that if you look at the model, the seasonal parameter is 6. And when you put it into the arima() function it gives error.
Another thing is that I would like the confidence interval for the predecited values!

Comment: Yes, as @agstudy stated, your data vector is too short to support a seasonal parameter as large as 6 (at least with R's implementation, I don't know enough about the model to comment on theoretical requirements).  You have the standard errors from the `predict` output, so using a t or normal distribution (again I don't know enough details about the model as to which assumptions it makes) you should be able to get the confidence intervals.